# MessageBoxButton.YesNo Tutorial

Tags: c#

I have a little problem again but this time it regards the `MessageBoxButton.YesNo`. This is my problem: I don't know what's the right syntax so that if I hit Enter(keyboard) or click Yes, the `Application.Exit();` will execute and if I hit Esc(keyboard) or  click No, the `Application.Exit();` will not execute. This is my code:

```
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?","Application Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the specific kind of UI you're using as a tag, e.g. WinForms, WPF, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to actually store off and check the result of the message box

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Application Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: If it answers your question, mark it as an answer rather than a Thank you comment.

Comment: oh sorry sir im just i newbie here in this forums but this forums really helps for beginners like me

Comment: @YukimotoOtomikuy This will make it to where other people who are looking to answer unanswered questions will not waste time coming to this question.

Comment: @YukimotoOtomikuy There should be a check mark outline by my answer that you can click

Answer (score 7):

The MessageBox.Show() function returns a DialogResult enumeration, and when you specify the Yes/No buttons, you would get one of those results:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?",
                    "Application Exit", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
  Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use DialogResult

```
if(MessageBox.Show("....", ..., MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes){
  Apllication.Exit();
}
```